# Vertical line to the left of section lines in memior TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir, typography

I have a memoir TOC with defined as in the MWE below, which is fine, but I'd like to add a a vertical line slightly to the left of the section lines, but under the chapter line.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\definecolor{ku}{RGB}{144, 26, 30}
% TOC adapted from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/380170/14052

\renewcommand*{\cftchapterleader}{}
\renewcommand*{\cftsectionleader}{}
\renewcommand*{\cftsubsectionleader}{}

\renewcommand*{\cftchapterformatpnum}[1]{~\textperiodcentered~\textcolor{ku}{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\cftsectionformatpnum}[1]{~\textperiodcentered~\textcolor{ku}{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\cftsubsectionformatpnum}[1]{~\textperiodcentered~\textcolor{ku}{#1}}

\renewcommand{\cftchapterafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}
\renewcommand{\cftsectionafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsectionafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}

\renewcommand{\cftchapterfont}{\normalfont\normalsize} 
\renewcommand{\cftsectionfont}{\normalfont\small}

\renewcommand\cftchaptername{\scshape\chaptername~}
\renewcommand\cftappendixname{\scshape\appendixname~}

\setrmarg{3.55em plus 1fil}
\setsecnumdepth{subsection}
\maxsecnumdepth{subsection}
\settocdepth{subsection}

\begin{document}
    \frontmatter
    \chapter{Abstract}
    \lipsum[1]
    \chapter{Acknowldgements}
    \lipsum[1]
    \tableofcontents
    \mainmatter

    \chapter{Introduction}
    \section{Summary of previous results}
    \lipsum[3]
    \section{Related work}
    \lipsum[3]
    \section{Definitions and Conventions}
    \lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

[image: example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you want but try adding the following to your preamble:

```
\renewcommand{\cftsectionname}{$\vert$\space} % or
\renewcommand{\cftsectionname}{\rule{1mm}{10pt}\space} % or
%\renewcommand{\cftsectionname}{...}
```

Try playing around with `\cftsectionname` (which puts its argument before the section number in the ToC) to get what you are after.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've added an example image of what I'm after.

Comment: @msx As I said, try setting the `\cftsectionname` to get what you are after.

Comment: \renewcommand\cftsectionname{\smash{\rule[-4pt]{4pt}{\baselineskip+1pt}}\space} produces the desired result. Thanks!

Comment: @msx Glad you got it sorted. I was going to suggest using a zero-sized picture. Essentially replacing your `\smash{...}\space` with `\begin{picture}(0,0)\put(0,0){...}\end{picture}\space`. Just another way of doing it.